# Define a Fallback Font in for SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, fonts

I'm working with an existing WPF (.NET 4.5) application that includes a feature allowing a user to enter text data into the WPF app and then generate a report of that data using SSRS (SQL Server 2008 R2 - VS2008).  I'm also quite new to SSRS.

Is there a way to mimic the behavior of the WPF font handling defined in GlobalUserInterface.CompositeFonts in the SSRS so that Unicode characters not defined by the primary font (Arial) fallback to the same fonts they do in WPF?

My understanding is that .css is not an option for reports generated from SSRS.

I found www.keepitsimpleandfast.com/2011/11/how-to-implement-style-sheets-in-your.html which provides a workaround for styles, but doesn't go far enough in allowing cascading.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option of using Fallback font for SSRS. If you are working with server side reporting RDL, You can create your own [Custom Report Item(CRI)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345231.aspx) which could have this option of fallback font. CRIs are not trivial to build but they are very powerful. CRIs are not available with client reporting or RDLC though.